# functions are not supported in Qt Quick ui form

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I'm trying to open a link in my Qt Quick application, I get `functions are not supported in Qt Quick  ui form` warning, the application works, I want to get rid of the warning, How can fix this warning?.

`AboutForm.ui.qml` file

```
Text {
    id: license
    x: 40
    y: 207
    color: "#ffffff"
    text: qsTr("<a href='https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html'>GNU General Public License, version 2 or later</a>")
    font.pixelSize: 16
    // the editor complains about this function
    onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally("https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton
        cursorShape: parent.hoveredLink ? Qt.PointingHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
    }
}
```

and my `About.qml` file is empty.

```
import QtQuick 2.4

AboutForm {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html):

> You can use Qt Creator wizards to create UI forms that have the filename extension .ui.qml. The UI forms contain a purely declarative subset of the QML language. It is recommended that you edit the forms in the Design mode. However, exporting items as alias properties is a commercial only feature, and therefore you must use the Edit mode to do it if you are using the open source version of Qt Creator. Qt Creator enforces the use of the supported QML features by displaying error messages.
>
> The following features are not supported:
>
> - JavaScript blocks
> - Function definitions
> - **Function calls (except qsTr)**
> - Other bindings than pure expressions
> - Signal handlers
> - States in other items than the root item
> - Root items that are not derived from QQuickItem or Item
>
> The following types are not supported:
>
> - Behavior
> - Binding
> - Canvas
> - Component
> - Shader Effect
> - Timer
> - Transform
> - Transition

The solution I propose is to suppress the warnings with the following:

```
// @disable-check M222
onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally(
                     "https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html")
```

References:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/66429/what-is-sign-in-disable-check-m16
- http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html#list-of-javascript-and-qml-checks

Answer (score 1):

AboutForm.ui.qml

```
// add this:    
property alias license: license    

Text {
        id: license
        x: 40
        y: 207
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("<a href='https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html'>GNU General Public License, version 2 or later</a>")
        font.pixelSize: 16
        // Remove this line


    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton
        cursorShape: parent.hoveredLink ? Qt.PointingHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
    }
}
```

About.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4

AboutForm {
     // add this line
     license.onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally("https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt Quick UI Form is supposed to be a QML file with only visible elements. There is no business logic presented here ([Qt-forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/72569/functions-are-not-supported-in-a-qt-quick-ui-form/2)).

When you create a Qt Quick UI Form by using the Qt Creator, it will create two files:

1. YourItemForm.ui.qml
2. YourItem.qml <--- This one includes the logic.

`YourItem.qml`:

```
YourItemForm {
  button1 {
    text: data_provider.get("button_text")
  }
}
```

`YourItemForm.ui.qml`:

```
Item {
  property alias button1 : button1 
  Button {
    id: button1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to open the external link from the main.qml instead from the UI itself.

In AboutForm.ui.qml add

property int externalcall:1

```
        MouseArea {
            id: mousearea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
            onClicked: externalcall=2
        }
```

then inside the main.qml application window create an on externalcall changed and inside this function open the link. If it is not clear, let me know to give an example.